# how to get the value of json element without the double quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I generate json from datatable by this function:

```
   public string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder3(DataTable table)
    {
        var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JSONString.Append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               // JSONString.Append("{");
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        if (j == 1)
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"[" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "]\",");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"[" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "]\",");
                        }

                    }
                    else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {

                        if (j == 1)
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"[" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "]\"");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"["  + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "]\"");
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (i == table.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("");
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONString.Append(",");
                }
            }
            JSONString.Append("]");
        }
        return JSONString.ToString();
    }
```

and then i retrieve the return value by calling the method thru ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ProjMonitor/Report/ProjectMonitoringSummary.aspx/GetlineChart",
       contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{id:'"+idproyek+"'}",
      //  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) { 

  var data = msg.d   
 }
```

});

the msg or the response received from the server:

```
{"d":"{ \"dataTarget\":[\"[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]\",\"[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]\"], \"dataRealisasi\" :[\"[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]\",\"[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]\"]}"}
```

I need a value of a variable like this without the double quotes:

```
[{
    "name": "Proyeksi Target", 
    "data" : [
        [ Date.UTC(2016, 3, 01), 10.00 ],
        [ Date.UTC(2016, 1, 01), 5.00 ]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "Realisasi", 
    "data": [
        [Date.UTC(2016, 3, 01), 10.00 ],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 1, 01), 5.00 ]
    ]
}]
```

Can you guys help me?

i tried JSON.Parse(msg.d) but error : Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function

what i really need is put the dynamic value of highcharts JS element below, with the dataTarget and dataRealisasi can be changed by calling method with parameter thru jquery ajax.

```
  $('#container3').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monitoring Proyek'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Proyek'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Target (%)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} %'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series:  [{
            "name": "Proyeksi Target",          
            "data": [ dataTarget

            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Realisasi',
            data: [
               dataRealisasi
            ]
        }]

         });
```

the format of dataTarget and dataRealisasi should be like this

```
 [
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.25],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 1), 1.66],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 10), 1.8],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 19), 1.76],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 25), 2.62],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19), 2.41],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 30), 2.05],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 14), 1.7],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 24), 1.1],
                    [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 0]

]
```

withouth quotes.. please help

Comment: We need to see the code you use to generate the string.

Comment: are you really speaking of a string, not an object?

Comment: please add the raw string.

Comment: @user1851384: Is this response of any rest resource?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan edited

Comment: Don't build your own JSON string. Provide a class to JSON.Net.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for parsing a JSON string.

```
var array = JSON.parse(object.d);
```

You have not a valid [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), because

- leading zeroes
- parenthesis
- function/method calls

The other solution, I do not recommend, is in this case

```
array = eval(object.d);
```

The better approach is to organize the data in the manner of not using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Answer (score 0):

The only approach to work with this string is to use ReGex to remove what is out of the scope for a JSON object or array.

```js
var str = '{' +
    '"d": "[{' +
    '"name": "Proyeksi Target",' +
    '"data" : [' +
    '[ Date.UTC(2016, 3, 01), 10.00 ],' +
    '[ Date.UTC(2016, 1, 01), 5.00 ]' +
    ']' +
    '}, {' +
    '"name": "Realisasi",' +
    '"data": [' +
    '[Date.UTC(2016, 3, 01), 10.00 ],' +
    '[Date.UTC(2016, 1, 01), 5.00]' +
    ']' +
    '}]"' +
    '}';
// fix syntax errors
str = str.match(/("\[\{".*}]")/g)[0];
str = str.substr(1, str.length - 2).replace(/(Date.UTC[^)]+\))/g, '"$1"');
// convert to object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
var myStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2);
document.write(myStr);
```

Comment: i dont understand i cant call JSON.Parse and JSON.Stringify... but i already include the json.js...

Comment: i got the str  from jquery ajax with json datatype . the response of ajax is like this :

Comment: {"d":"{ \"dataTarget\":[{\"[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]\"},{\"[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]\"}], \"dataRealisasi\" :[{\"[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]\"},{\"[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]\"}]}"}