# Parsing unquoted JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

What is the easiest method to parse unquoted JSON string?

for example if I have the following:

```
{property1:value1,property2:value2}
```

The following throws an error:

```
JSON.parse( badJSONString );
```

since proper JSON should have keys and values quoted: `{"property1":"value1"}`

Comment: Where are you getting that string from? Is there a way to make it have the quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not possible.

Comment: I think your option is to make RegEx with your string

Comment: @ASDFGerte you should probably delete that comment. "Possible" and "Advisable" are two entirely different things.

Comment: eval will work only when the keys isn't quoted, but in my example I need the keys and values to be quoted.

Comment: @John Ress you are either going to have to correct the source data or you are going to have to write your own parser

Comment: You could make a rudimentary parser that goes through and finds the start and end of each key and value and adds quotes. Whether via RegEx as explained or some other method. Otherwise the best and safest way is to change your source data.

Comment: @K.AlanBates I explicitly said that it should probably not even be taken if there are no security concerns, calling it "evil". Anyways, i removed the comment either way.

Comment: Is your data consistent? Parsing this is hard if you have to account formal the edge cases like `{property1:value,withcomma}` but easy if you know you won't have these cases.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ...not trying to be mean with the "takedown." Just don't send anyone 'that' way, even with disclaimers lol

Comment: An interesting method would be removing the curly braces and parsing the string as set of pairs. The following is an example of implementation and if you expect several types of values, a value parser is required.
`data.replace(/[{}]/g, '').split(',').map(val => val.split(':')).reduce((init, [key, val]) => Object.assign(init, { [key]: yourValueParser(val) } ), {})`.

Comment: @K.AlanBates The issue is someone will mention it either way, that's why my comment was also beginning with "just a heads-up". See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987868/parse-json-with-no-quotes-in-javascript) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201349/how-to-get-the-value-of-json-element-without-the-double-quote), where each time, be that with warnings, the name that should not be mentioned is still being mentioned.

Comment: @Reuven Chacha Since I have only text values I think this method will work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is consistent (and that might be a big if), you can process the string with a very simple function. The following will fail with certain strings that have commas or colons in the values or string like `'{property1:val:ue1 ,property2:val,ue2}'` but those are going to be problematic anyway without some delimiters in the data.

```js
let bad = '{property1:value1,property2:value2}'
let obj = bad.slice(1, -1).split(/\s?,\s?/)
    .map(item => item.split(':'))
    .reduce((a, [key, val]) => Object.assign(a, {[key]: val}), {})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be the following:

```js
var initial = "{property1:value1,property2:value2}"; // string (unquoted JSON)

var cleaned = initial.trim().substring(1, initial.length - 1); // remove `{` and `}`

var kvPair = cleaned.split(',');              // get an array like ["property1:value1", "property2:value2"]
var final = {};
var split;
for (var i = 0, l = kvPair.length; i < l; i++) {
  split = kvPair[i].split(':');               // get an array like ["property1","value1"]
  final[split[0].trim()] = split[1].trim();   // add value X to property X (remove whitespaces at the beginning and end)
}
console.log(final)
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/ghyu4zfj/21/)