# Javascript get object from string

Tags: javascript

I have a string inside a variable that looks like this:

```
var mystring = "firstword { name: 'peter' }";
```

I know it's all a string but visually the content after `'firstword'` is / looks like an object.

My question is...how can I grad that object or remove the first word so I have put the object into another variable?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried that isn't working. You should generally only try to transform JSON into objects, but what's inside the brackets isn't JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval) and [Parsing unquoted JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430762)

Comment: Remove everything upto the first `{` using `slice` and `indexOf("{")`. Then use ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Your string isnt valid json. A valid json string would like the following. Removing the substring "firstword" makes it parsable for json.

Edit v2: Check the comments of your question there is a link to modify the string in a way it can be parsed. [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval)

```js
var mystring = 'firstword { "name": "peter" }';
mystring = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf("{"));
var obj = JSON.parse(mystring);
document.write(obj.name);
```

Comment: While this removes the first word it doesn't produce an object that the OP wants to put into a new variable.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood his question, I will edit it, thanks!