# What is a concise way to parse a javascript string that is a comma delimited list of key=value pairs?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to parse a string into a JavaScript array or map. The string I'm trying to parse looks like:

```
"{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}"
```

The code I currently have works, but it's a bit lengthy.

```js
str = "{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}";
str = str.replace(/{/g, '');
str = str.replace(/}/g, '');
var strMap = {};
str.split(', ').forEach(function(x) {
  var arr = x.split('=');
  strMap[arr[0]] = arr[1];
});

console.log(strMap)
```

That gets me what I want, but it's not very clean. Someone suggested I use `JSON.parse`, but it doesn't seem to work as the string isn't in valid JSON format.

Is there a concise way to do it so I'm not manually parsing the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval) and [Parsing unquoted JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430762)

Comment: can you change the json to proper format from where it is originated ?

Comment: The only clean way to do this is to fix the creation

Comment: @ThomasClayson well, what should `"{key=1}"` produce, then? `{key: 1}` or `{key: "1"}`?

Comment: Why isn't this "very clean"? Seems quite good to me. You can reduce the 2 `str.replace(...)` into one by using "or" which is a pipe `|`. `str.replace(/{|}/g, '');` which saves an extra line of code.

Comment: @VLAZ there is no way to know what was intended from the original string.

Comment: When I say "very clean", I mean that I would prefer not to manually parse the string. 
I'll likely go with what most people have suggested and try to change the initial string to be valid JSON format.

Comment: @ThomasClayson bingo!

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string by comma and whitespace and splir key/value pairs for the properties of the new object. The result has strings as value.

```js
const getPair = ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v });

var string = "{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}",
    result = Object.assign(...string
        .slice(1, -1)
        .split(/,\s+/)
        .map(p => getPair(p.split('=')))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Or take (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const getPair = ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v });

var string = "{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}",
    result = Object.fromEntries(string
        .slice(1, -1)
        .split(/,\s+/)
        .map(p => p.split('='))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: op should close the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some ES6 features to pretty easily put together a decent naive solution (format as outlined by your example).

```
const example = "{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}";
const stripped = example.substring(1, example.length - 1);
const map = stripped.split(",")
                    .map(pair => pair.trim())
                    .reduce((result, current) => {
                       const [key, value] = current.split("=");
                       return {
                          ...result,
                          key: value
                       };
                    }, {});
```